# Setting the Android Hamburger and Overflow Menu accessibility Item Labels

Tags: android, accessibility

Im employing Accessibility Scanner to check my current Android Application.

It has supplied a number of suggestions that I cannot see how to action...

Namely how do you go about setting an Item Label a screen reader can consume for the Hamburger and overflow menu icons?

Is this possible either through xml or programmatically?

My Toolbar layout resembles this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/tool_bar"
        android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        app:subtitleTextColor="#BBFFFFFF"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/paddingView"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_progressbar_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_progressbar_size"
            android:layout_gravity="end" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loadingProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_progressbar_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_progressbar_size"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/main_text"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Are you supplying your own `Toolbar`, or are you using the default `ActionBar`?

Comment: @MikeM. im supplying my own Toolbar

Comment: Well, the navigation button (hamburger) label can be set with the `app:navigationContentDescription` attribute in XML, or with one of [the corresponding methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar#setNavigationContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)) in your code. If you're using an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` for the hamburger, though, I should mention that it already sets that description itself, depending on its state, from the last two arguments you pass in its constructor call.

Comment: As for the overflow button, that might have to be handled in the theme, 'cause that's actually a function of the menu presenter rather than the `Toolbar`, and I don't think there are any such similar direct methods for that. If you look at Solution 2 in [these examples I recently put together for something else](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lj-pZPxSMPgoAVseu0Eqwbvpk88VDzFd/view?usp=sharing), you should see how you could set `<item name="android:contentDescription">` there instead of the ID. Also just FYI, by default that description is set to `R.string.abc_action_menu_overflow_description`

Comment: app:navigationContentDescription this fixes the Hamburger menu

Comment: In rereading your question just now, I think I might've misunderstood the second part. Did you mean the individual menu items in the overflow popup? Or the three-dot button that opens it?

Comment: just the three dots menu, thanks for your time in sorting this

Comment: OK, well, I guess I did understand. I got a chance to test it, and the second example with the `android:contentDescription` substitution does work as expected. I thought that button always has one by default, though, so I'm not sure why the scan caught that.